# What is a good solution for calculating an average where the sum of all values exceeds a double's limits?

Tags: java, algorithm, statistics

I have a requirement to calculate the average of a very large set of doubles (10^9 values).  The sum of the values exceeds the upper bound of a double, so does anyone know any neat little tricks for calculating an average that doesn't require also calculating the sum?

I am using Java 1.5.

Comment: Define "average", could be mean, median or mode. The last two don't require you to add up all the values.

Comment: I was using it in the vernacular sense, i.e. arithmetic mean.

Comment: @James Very few people would say 'average' when they want the median or the mode.  While I agree it isn't precise, generally outside of statistics departments most people assume average == mean.

Comment: An efficient and numerically stable algorithm for mean and empirical variance you can find at http://www.johndcook.com/standard_deviation.html or for parallel computation in http://infoserve.sandia.gov/sand_doc/2008/086212.pdf

Comment: @jug, if you had posted this as an answer I would have upvoted you!  Plus I can't get to your second link, is it broken?

Comment: @Simon: If I click the second link, then it works for me (it's a pdf by Phillippe Pebay with the title "Formulas for Robust, One-Pass Parallel Computation of Covariances and Arbitrary-Order Statistical Moments"). You get it also on second place on google's advanced search with the two words pebay and covariance in the field "all these words". By the way I used a comment so that the references don't get buried below all the answers given.

Comment: How accurate do you have to be? You could divide each number by 10^9, and chop the result to say 4-6 digits (decimal places) - divide by #of values and mutiply again by 10^9.

Answer (score 219, accepted):

You can [calculate the mean iteratively](http://www.heikohoffmann.de/htmlthesis/node134.html). This algorithm is simple, fast, you have to process each value just once, and the variables never get larger than the largest value in the set, so you won't get an overflow.

```
double mean(double[] ary) {
  double avg = 0;
  int t = 1;
  for (double x : ary) {
    avg += (x - avg) / t;
    ++t;
  }
  return avg;
}
```

Inside the loop `avg` always is the average value of all values processed so far. In other words, if all the values are finite you should not get an overflow.

Comment: I think this as a solid solution to the OPs question.  Nice.

Comment: If you have a large number of values to average (which is the only case in which you would have the problem that the sum overflows a double), then this algorithm will have severe underflow issues. Essentially, at some point, (x-avg) becomes zero.

Comment: you only have the underflow issues when x and average is very close to each other, so I do not think it is an issue

Comment: note also that if underflow is a concern, the order of magnitude of avg can be monitored and the avg re-baselined by a fixed multiplier. x would have to be divided by the multiplier in the above code. Finally, with this size of set, it is highly likely that random sampling will produce an acceptable result (engineering is about being good enough, not perfect).

Comment: @Martin B: This method is numerically stable and recommended in Knuth, The Art of Computer Programming Vol 2, section 4.2.2. It is by the way the only sensible answer posted until now, so please upvote!!!

Comment: Couldn't the largest variable actually be 2x the largest value in the set? For example, if the array was `[-100, 100]`, on the second iteration, `x - avg` would result in `100 - -100` or `200` which is actually 2x the magnitude of the largest element in the set.

Comment: @socom1880: `avg` always stays between `min` and `max`; the result of the subtraction is always not larger than `max - min` in magnitude; same holds for the result of the division.

Comment: It may be worth noting that, in my tests, the iterative method was slightly less accurate than the sum method for values not overflowing a double.  (At least for my ordered test case.)  I theorize that the iterative method gives more weight to the first values, in that the precision of much later values is effectively reduced.  However, the difference in the avg of 1e9 values was very small, in my test; about 1e-9.

Comment: Be careful using this function. There might be overflow if data during start are too large and too small. For example, what if the array is [Double.MIN, Double.MAX]. You will end up with overflow because the divider of the first and second round are too small. 

Let's proof by define MIN = -127 and MAX=128, First Round:: avg += (-127 - 0) /1 = -127). Then the second round avg += (128 - (-127))/2 //Boom overflow because 128 -(-127) > MAX

Answer (score 12):

The very first issue I'd like to ask you is this:

- Do you know the number of values beforehand?

If not, then you have little choice but to sum, and count, and divide, to do the average. If `Double` isn't high enough precision to handle this, then tough luck, you can't use `Double`, you need to find a data type that can handle it.

If, on the other hand, you *do* know the number of values beforehand, you can look at what you're really doing and change *how* you do it, but keep the overall result.

The average of N values, stored in some collection A, is this:

```
A[0]   A[1]   A[2]   A[3]          A[N-1]   A[N]
---- + ---- + ---- + ---- + .... + ------ + ----
 N      N      N      N               N       N
```

To calculate subsets of this result, you can split up the calculation into equally sized sets, so you can do this, for 3-valued sets (assuming the number of values is divisable by 3, otherwise you need a different divisor)

```
/ A[0]   A[1]   A[2] \   / A[3]   A[4]   A[5] \   //      A[N-1]   A[N] \
| ---- + ---- + ---- |   | ---- + ---- + ---- |   \\    + ------ + ---- |
\  3      3      3   /   \  3      3      3   /   //        3       3   /
 --------------------- +  --------------------  + \\      --------------
          N                        N                        N
         ---                      ---                      ---
          3                        3                        3
```

Note that you need **equally sized sets**, otherwise numbers in the last set, which will not have enough values compared to all the sets before it, will have a higher impact on the final result.

Consider the numbers 1-7 in sequence, if you pick a set-size of 3, you'll get this result:

```
/ 1   2   3 \   / 4   5   6 \   / 7 \ 
| - + - + - | + | - + - + - | + | - |
\ 3   3   3 /   \ 3   3   3 /   \ 3 /
 -----------     -----------     ---
      y               y           y
```

which gives:

```
     2   5   7/3
     - + - + ---
     y   y    y
```

If y is 3 for all the sets, you get this:

```
     2   5   7/3
     - + - + ---
     3   3    3
```

which gives:

```
2*3   5*3    7
--- + --- + ---
 9     9     9
```

which is:

```
6   15   7
- + -- + -
9    9   9
```

which totals:

```
28
-- ~ 3,1111111111111111111111.........1111111.........
 9
```

The average of 1-7, is 4. Obviously this won't work. Note that if you do the above exercise with the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 0 (note the two zeroes at the end there), then you'll get the above result.

In other words, if you can't split the number of values up into equally sized sets, the last set will be counted as though it has the same number of values as all the sets preceeding it, but it will be padded with zeroes for all the missing values.

So, **you need equally sized sets**. Tough luck if your original input set consists of a prime number of values.

What I'm worried about here though is loss of precision. I'm not entirely sure `Double` will give you good enough precision in such a case, if it initially cannot hold the entire sum of the values.

Comment: You can trivially have not-equally-sized sets if you weight them appropriately.

Comment: Please tell me how that works, I would love to learn how to do this correctly because I have a similar problem in a private project of mine and I have yet to find a good solution! For instance, tell me how to weigh the simple sequence of the values from 1 through 7, in such a way that I don't have to sum them all up together.

Comment: ... let me emphasis this. Please prove me wrong, I need this solution as well.

Comment: my answer has the trivial case for non-equally sized sets.

Comment: well, as does Davide's, though he wasn't explicit about the weighting is done.

Comment: @Lasse ask the detailed question on that famous site called stackoverflow, and you'll get several good answers :-) If you want **my** answer, be sure to link your question under one of my answers - I think it's trivial, so I'm not editing mine here per your request in a comment to yours

Comment: Ok, I'll pick up that gauntlet.

Comment: Ok, posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931359/how-to-reduce-calculation-of-average-to-sub-sets-in-a-general-way, please let me know if you think I've changed the problem in any significant way.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen In your example with numbers 1 - 7, if you chose to divide it into sets of 2, you would have (1,2), (3,4), (5,6), (3.5, 3.5). I just calculated this using your subset method and it comes out to an average of 4. With (3/7) + 1 + (11/7) + 1, for each subset respectively.

Comment: There is a comment by a new user (http://stackoverflow.com/users/6643428/zkutch)  --- I leave to you to decide if it makes sense: *About answer from Lasse V. Karlsen with tag equally sized sets: when take numbers 1..7 they average, obviously, is 28/7=4, but author of answer divide it on 9 in place of 7 and this mistake bring as proof of that groups should be equally sized. Yes, if you take numbers 1..7 0 0 then this, now 9, numbers have different average. Again this means nothing for proof that groups should be equally sized.*

Comment: *May be there is some other way to argue why it is need to take same amount in all groups, but brought formulas proof nothing. You can group numbers in any way, if you keep mathematical equality, then this cannot impact on result. Have somebody normal explanations or proof?*

Answer (score 11):

Apart from using the better approaches already suggested, you can use [BigDecimal](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) to make your calculations. (Bear in mind it is immutable)

Comment: Don't make life more difficult for yourself unless absolutely necessary - if you need to deal with very large numbers or high precision and you can sacrifice time then using complex number types is a good way to go.

Comment: Slower is a relative term. In the case of calculating the average of 10^9 values, with BigDecimal, slow is several minutes (maybe even 30)... If a faster algorithm is required, the BigDecimal approach would be great to verify the faster implementation.

Comment: Bad idea, this will create 10^9 objects for nothing. Since all input numbers fit into double range, the mean will also fit into double range, thus a solution using doubles only is possible.

Comment: Of course. I did propose using the better approaches already suggested. (Some of those objects should be garbage-collected at some point.)

Answer (score 11):

IMHO, the most robust way of solving your problem is

1. sort your set
2. split in groups of elements whose sum wouldn't overflow - since they are sorted, this is fast and easy
3. do the sum in each group - and divide by the group size
4. do the sum of the group's sum's (possibly calling this same algorithm recursively) - be aware that if the groups will not be equally sized, you'll have to weight them by their size

One nice thing of this approach is that it scales nicely if you have a really large number of elements to sum - and a large number of processors/machines to use to do the math

Comment: Note that the size of the sets must be equal, ie. 3-value sets, or 15-value sets, or whatever-value sets, but you can't mix different value sets, or values in smaller sets will have a higher impact on the result than those in larger sets.

Comment: This approach can also be made multi-threaded to make sue of all the CPUs in your system.

Comment: You want to avoid sorting a large collection of items if you can.  The average does not depend upon the order of items, so this is a lot of extra work.  Scanning for the largest N elements would give you enough information to make informed group size choices I think.

Comment: @Lasse not necessarily. You just have to weight the sum appropriately (=depending on the size set)

Comment: @Will: in math, the sum does not depend on the order of items. In floating pointing arithmetics, it does. The most robust way to solve the sum problem, is indeed the one I wrote: sort and sum in chunks. It is not the fastest, but it's safe, and easily parallelized.

Comment: in Java terms, 'sorting a set' sounds inappropriate ;)

Comment: Are you dividing in there somewhere?  :-)

Comment: I've picked up the gauntlet, please tell me where I'm being a fool: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931359/how-to-reduce-calculation-of-average-to-sub-sets-in-a-general-way

Comment: And note that I'm going to have/find a reallllly good excuse for why I'm not seeing the solution right now, regardless of how obvious it is :) Like, it's 1 in the morning sunday ... :) - Seriously though, I really can't see this solution and I do have present code that suffers a similar problem (not with the limitation to "double", but more about how I retrieve the values) where I need to calculate the averaage; any good solution to this which makes me slap my forehead would be a great benefit.

Comment: Bad idea, sorting a large array is time consuming. You better group values into large and small ones as you iterate over them. See my solution.

Comment: Note that this, as well as most of the other answers, requires you to store all of the data in memory (to sort it, split it into groups, etc.), which may not be possible if we're talking 10^9 values (depends on the platform, obviously). My answer and martinus's do not require storing the data in memory.

Comment: If you want a faster sort using less memory, just sort on the exponent, not the mantissa.

Answer (score 11):

Please clarify the potential ranges of the values.

Given that a double has a range ~= +/-10^308, and you're summing 10^9 values, the apparent range suggested in your question is values of the order of 10^299.

That seems somewhat, well, unlikely...

If your values really *are* that large, then with a normal double you've got only 17 significant decimal digits to play with, so you'll be throwing away about 280 digits worth of information before you can even think about averaging the values.

I would also note (since no-one else has) that for any set of numbers `X`:

```
mean(X) = sum(X[i] - c)  +  c
          -------------
                N
```

for any arbitrary constant `c`.

In this particular problem, setting `c = min(X)` *might* dramatically reduce the risk of overflow during the summation.

May I humbly suggest that the problem statement is incomplete...?

Answer (score 6):

You could take the average of averages of equal-sized subsets of numbers that don't exceed the limit.

Comment: A much better example of this is below: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930454/what-is-a-good-solution-for-calculating-an-average-where-the-sum-of-all-values-ex/1930913#1930913

Answer (score 6):

A double can be divided by a power of 2 without loss of precision. So if your only problem if the absolute size of the sum you could pre-scale your numbers before summing them.  But with a dataset of this size, there is still the risk that you will hit a situation where you are adding small numbers to a large one, and the small numbers will end up being mostly (or completely) ignored.

for instance,  when you add  2.2e-20  to 9.0e20 the result is 9.0e20 because once the scales are adjusted so that they numbers can be added together, the smaller number is 0.  Doubles can only hold about 17 digits, and you would need more than 40 digits to add these two numbers together without loss.

So, depending on your data set and how many digits of precision you can afford to loose, you may need to do other things.   Breaking the data into sets will help, but a better way to preserve precision might be to determine a rough average (you may already know this number).  then subtract each value from the rough average before you sum it.  That way you are summing the distances from the average, so your sum should never get very large.

Then you take the average delta, and add it to your rough sum to get the correct average.  Keeping track of the min and max delta will also tell you how much precision you lost during the summing process.  If you have lots of time and need a very accurate result, you can iterate.

Comment: To sum large and small values, one should use Kahan summations.

Comment: "determine a rough average (you may already know this number). then subtract each value from the rough average before you sum it. That way you are summing the distances from the average, so your sum should never get very large."
Given a completely accurate "rough average" of MAXDOUBLE/2, and an input of six numbers, 0, 0, 0, MAXDOUBLE, MAXDOUBLE, MAXDOUBLE, ...wouldn't this fail?

Answer (score 5):

divide all values by the set size and then sum it up

Comment: you might hit underflows, though, instead of overflow

Comment: If dividing by the number of elements in the total input will give "underflow", as in "loss of precision", then I'd venture a guess that *double* isn't a good enough data type for this problem.

Comment: @davide: java double range is 4.94065645841246544e-324d to 1.79769313486231570e+308d,  if the numbers are so small to cause an underflow then there would not have been the risk of an overflow.   if there is a combination of large and small number its recommended to use the split sets approach described in the other good  answers  but it will make the function a bit less readable, then the simplistic approche.

Comment: Right direction, but this naïve approach this will lead to loss of precision. You better divide large values by some power of two, and leave small values as they are. See my solution.

Answer (score 5):

Option 1 is to use an arbitrary-precision library so you don't have an upper-bound.

Other options (which lose precision) are to sum in groups rather than all at once, or to divide before summing.

Comment: Most of the other answers are assuming they know more about your problem than they do.  These are the correct general-purpose answers.  Without knowing more about your problem, including all your requirements, more about your specific data, etc, any optimization advice is worthless.

Answer (score 3):

So I don't repeat myself so much, let me state that I am assuming that the list of numbers is normally distributed, and that you can sum many numbers before you overflow.  The technique still works for non-normal distros, but somethings will not meet the expectations I describe below.

--

Sum up a sub-series, keeping track of how many numbers you eat, until you approach the overflow, then take the average.  This will give you an average a0, and count n0.  Repeat until you exhaust the list.  Now you should have many ai, ni.

Each ai and ni should be relatively close, with the possible exception of the last bite of the list.  You can mitigate that by under-biting near the end of the list.

You can combine any subset of these ai, ni by picking any ni in the subset (call it np) and dividing all the ni in the subset by that value.  The max size of the subsets to combine is the roughly constant value of the n's.

The ni/np should be close to one.  Now sum ni/np * ai and multiple by np/(sum ni), keeping track of sum ni.  This gives you a new ni, ai combination, if you need to repeat the procedure.

If you will need to repeat (i.e., the number of ai, ni pairs is much larger than the typical ni), try to keep relative n sizes constant by combining all the averages at one n level first, then combining at the next level, and so on.

Comment: fyi, this is essentially Davide's answer, without the pre-sort.  The pre-sort should reduce numerical error, but perhaps not at the level that matters relative to the expense of the sort.

Comment: Can you give a specific example of how to handle the sequence 1-7? Your answer looks promising, but perhaps it's late, but I can't wrap my head around it fully :P

Answer (score 3):

First of all, make yourself familiar with the internal representation of `double` values. Wikipedia should be a good starting point.

Then, consider that doubles are expressed as "value plus exponent" where exponent is a power of two. The limit of the largest double value is an upper limit of the exponent, and not a limit of the value! So you may divide all large input numbers by a large enough power of two. This should be safe for all large enough numbers. You can re-multiply the result with the factor to check whether you lost precision with the multiplication.

Here we go with an algorithm

```
public static double sum(double[] numbers) { 
  double eachSum, tempSum;
  double factor = Math.pow(2.0,30); // about as large as 10^9
  for (double each: numbers) {
    double temp = each / factor;
    if (t * factor != each) {
      eachSum += each;
    else {
      tempSum += temp;
    }
  }
  return (tempSum / numbers.length) * factor + (eachSum / numbers.length);
}
```

and dont be worried by the additional division and multiplication. The FPU will optimize the hell out of them since they are done with a power of two (for comparison imagine adding and removing digits at the end of a decimal numbers).

PS: *in addition, you may want to use [Kahan summation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm) to improve the precision. Kahan summation avoids loss of precision when very large and very small numbers are summed up.*

Answer (score 2):

A random sampling of a small set of the full dataset will often result in a 'good enough' solution.  You obviously have to make this determination yourself based on system requirements.  Sample size can be remarkably small and still obtain reasonably good answers.  This can be adaptively computed by calculating the average of an increasing number of randomly chosen  samples - the average will converge within some interval.

Sampling not only addresses the double overflow concern, but is much, much faster.  Not applicable for all problems, but certainly useful for many problems.

Comment: Sampling might be useful in some contexts, but normality has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 2):

I posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931359/how-to-reduce-calculation-of-average-to-sub-sets-in-a-general-way/1931759#1931759) to [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931359/how-to-reduce-calculation-of-average-to-sub-sets-in-a-general-way/) spawned from this one, realizing afterwards that my answer is better suited to this question than to that one.  I've reproduced it below.  I notice though, that my answer is similar to a combination of [Bozho's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930454/what-is-a-good-solution-for-calculating-an-average-where-the-sum-of-all-values-ex/1930492#1930492) and [Anon<sub><sup>.</sup></sub>'s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930454/what-is-a-good-solution-for-calculating-an-average-where-the-sum-of-all-values-ex/1930478#1930478).

As the other question was tagged language-agnostic, I chose C# for the code sample I've included.  Its relative ease of use and easy-to-follow syntax, along with its inclusion of a couple of features facilitating this routine (a DivRem function in the BCL, and support for iterator functions), as well as my own familiarity with it, made it a good choice for this problem.  Since the OP here is interested in a Java solution, but I'm not Java-fluent enough to write it effectively, it might be nice if someone could add a translation of this code to Java.

---

Some of the mathematical solutions here are very good.  Here's a simple technical solution.

Use a larger data type.  This breaks down into two possibilities:

1. Use a high-precision floating point library.  One who encounters a need to average a billion numbers probably has the resources to purchase, or the brain power to write, a 128-bit (or longer) floating point library.

   I understand the drawbacks here.  It would certainly be slower than using intrinsic types. You still might over/underflow if the number of values grows too high.  Yada yada.
2. If your values are integers or can be easily scaled to integers, keep your sum in a list of integers.  When you overflow, simply add another integer.  This is essentially a simplified implementation of the first option.  A simple <s>(untested)</s> example in C# follows

```
class BigMeanSet{
    List<uint> list = new List<uint>();

    public double GetAverage(IEnumerable<uint> values){
        list.Clear();
        list.Add(0);

        uint count = 0;

        foreach(uint value in values){
            Add(0, value);
            count++;
        }

        return DivideBy(count);
    }

    void Add(int listIndex, uint value){
        if((list[listIndex] += value) < value){ // then overflow has ocurred
            if(list.Count == listIndex + 1)
                list.Add(0);
            Add(listIndex + 1, 1);
        }
    }

    double DivideBy(uint count){
        const double shift = 4.0 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;

        double rtn       = 0;
        long   remainder = 0;

        for(int i = list.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--){
            rtn *= shift;
            remainder <<= 32;
            rtn += Math.DivRem(remainder + list[i], count, out remainder);
        }

        rtn += remainder / (double)count;

        return rtn;
    }
}
```

<s>Like I said, this is untested—I don't have a billion values I really want to average—so I've probably made a mistake or two, especially in the `DivideBy` function, but it should demonstrate the general idea.</s>

This should provide as much accuracy as a double can represent and should work for any number of 32-bit elements, up to 2<sup>32</sup> - 1.  If more elements are needed, then the `count` variable will need be expanded and the `DivideBy` function will increase in complexity, but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

In terms of efficiency, it should be as fast or faster than any other technique here, as it only requires iterating through the list once, only performs one division operation (well, one set of them), and does most of its work with integers.  I didn't optimize it, though, and I'm pretty certain it could be made slightly faster still if necessary.  Ditching the recursive function call and list indexing would be a good start.  Again, an exercise for the reader.  The code is intended to be easy to understand.

<s>If anybody more motivated than I am at the moment feels like verifying the correctness of the code, and fixing whatever problems there might be, please be my guest.</s>

---

I've now tested this code, and made a couple of small corrections (a missing pair of parentheses in the `List<uint>` constructor call, and an incorrect divisor in the final division of the `DivideBy` function).

I tested it by first running it through 1000 sets of random length (ranging between 1 and 1000) filled with random integers (ranging between 0 and 2<sup>32</sup> - 1).  These were sets for which I could easily and quickly verify accuracy by also running a canonical mean on them.

I then tested with 100<sup>*</sup> large series, with random length between 10<sup>5</sup> and 10<sup>9</sup>.  The lower and upper bounds of these series were also chosen at random, constrained so that the series would fit within the range of a 32-bit integer.  For any series, the results are easily verifiable as `(lowerbound + upperbound) / 2`.

<sup><sub><sup>*</sup>Okay, that's a little white lie.  I aborted the large-series test after about 20 or 30 successful runs.  A series of length 10<sup>9</sup> takes just under a minute and a half to run on my machine, so half an hour or so of testing this routine was enough for my tastes.</sub></sup>

For those interested, my test code is below:

```
static IEnumerable<uint> GetSeries(uint lowerbound, uint upperbound){
    for(uint i = lowerbound; i <= upperbound; i++)
        yield return i;
}

static void Test(){
    Console.BufferHeight = 1200;
    Random rnd = new Random();

    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
        uint[] numbers = new uint[rnd.Next(1, 1000)];
        for(int j = 0; j < numbers.Length; j++)
            numbers[j] = (uint)rnd.Next();

        double sum = 0;
        foreach(uint n in numbers)
            sum += n;

        double avg = sum / numbers.Length;
        double ans = new BigMeanSet().GetAverage(numbers);

        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1} - {2} = {3}", numbers.Length, avg, ans, avg - ans);

        if(avg != ans)
            Debugger.Break();
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        uint length     = (uint)rnd.Next(100000, 1000000001);
        uint lowerbound = (uint)rnd.Next(int.MaxValue - (int)length);
        uint upperbound = lowerbound + length;

        double avg = ((double)lowerbound + upperbound) / 2;
        double ans = new BigMeanSet().GetAverage(GetSeries(lowerbound, upperbound));

        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1} - {2} = {3}", length, avg, ans, avg - ans);

        if(avg != ans)
            Debugger.Break();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider this:

```
avg(n1)         : n1                               = a1
avg(n1, n2)     : ((1/2)*n1)+((1/2)*n2)            = ((1/2)*a1)+((1/2)*n2) = a2
avg(n1, n2, n3) : ((1/3)*n1)+((1/3)*n2)+((1/3)*n3) = ((2/3)*a2)+((1/3)*n3) = a3
```

So for any set of doubles of arbitrary size, you could do this (this is in C#, but I'm pretty sure it could be easily translated to Java):

```
static double GetAverage(IEnumerable<double> values) {
    int i = 0;
    double avg = 0.0;
    foreach (double value in values) {
        avg = (((double)i / (double)(i + 1)) * avg) + ((1.0 / (double)(i + 1)) * value);
        i++;
    }

    return avg;
}
```

Actually, this simplifies nicely into (already provided by martinus):

```
static double GetAverage(IEnumerable<double> values) {
    int i = 1;
    double avg = 0.0;
    foreach (double value in values) {
        avg += (value - avg) / (i++);
    }

    return avg;
}
```

I wrote a quick test to try this function out against the more conventional method of summing up the values and dividing by the count (`GetAverage_old`). For my input I wrote this quick function to return as many random positive doubles as desired:

```
static IEnumerable<double> GetRandomDoubles(long numValues, double maxValue, int seed) {
    Random r = new Random(seed);
    for (long i = 0L; i < numValues; i++)
        yield return r.NextDouble() * maxValue;

    yield break;
}
```

And here are the results of a few test trials:

```
long N = 100L;
double max = double.MaxValue * 0.01;

IEnumerable<double> doubles = GetRandomDoubles(N, max, 0);
double oldWay = GetAverage_old(doubles); // 1.00535024998431E+306
double newWay = GetAverage(doubles); // 1.00535024998431E+306

doubles = GetRandomDoubles(N, max, 1);
oldWay = GetAverage_old(doubles); // 8.75142021696299E+305
newWay = GetAverage(doubles); // 8.75142021696299E+305

doubles = GetRandomDoubles(N, max, 2);
oldWay = GetAverage_old(doubles); // 8.70772312848651E+305
newWay = GetAverage(doubles); // 8.70772312848651E+305
```

OK, but what about for 10^9 values?

```
long N = 1000000000;
double max = 100.0; // we start small, to verify accuracy

IEnumerable<double> doubles = GetRandomDoubles(N, max, 0);
double oldWay = GetAverage_old(doubles); // 49.9994879713857
double newWay = GetAverage(doubles); // 49.9994879713868 -- pretty close

max = double.MaxValue * 0.001; // now let's try something enormous

doubles = GetRandomDoubles(N, max, 0);
oldWay = GetAverage_old(doubles); // Infinity
newWay = GetAverage(doubles); // 8.98837362725198E+305 -- no overflow
```

Naturally, how acceptable this solution is will depend on your accuracy requirements. But it's worth considering.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the section for [cummulative moving average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average)

Comment: That wouldn't solve the problem as incrementing the average effectively requires recovering the Nth-1 sum, which here would still be large...

Answer (score 0):

In order to keep logic simple, and keep performance not the best but acceptable, i recommend you to use BigDecimal together with the primitive type. 
The concept is very simple, you use primitive type to sum values together, whenever the value will underflow or overflow, you move the calculate value to the BigDecimal, then reset it for the next sum calculation. One more thing you should aware is when you construct BigDecimal, you ought to always use String instead of double.

```
BigDecimal average(double[] values){
    BigDecimal totalSum = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    double tempSum = 0.00;
    for (double value : values){
        if (isOutOfRange(tempSum, value)) {
            totalSum = sum(totalSum, tempSum);
            tempSum = 0.00;
        }
        tempSum += value;
    }
    totalSum = sum(totalSum, tempSum);
    BigDecimal count = new BigDecimal(values.length);
    return totalSum.divide(count);
}

BigDecimal sum(BigDecimal val1, double val2){
    BigDecimal val = new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(val2));
    return val1.add(val);
}

boolean isOutOfRange(double sum, double value){
    // because sum + value > max will be error if both sum and value are positive
    // so I adapt the equation to be value > max - sum 
    if(sum >= 0.00 && value > Double.MAX - sum){
        return true;
    }

    // because sum + value < min will be error if both sum and value are negative
    // so I adapt the equation to be value < min - sum
    if(sum < 0.00 && value < Double.MIN - sum){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

From this concept, every time the result is underflow or overflow, we will keep that value into the bigger variable, this solution might a bit slowdown the performance due to the BigDecimal calculation, but it guarantee the runtime stability.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways, already mentioned:

```
int i = 1;
for ( double x : arr ){
    mean = mean + (x-mean)/n;
    ++n;
}
```

if the (x-mean)/n part becomes too small you can use

```
int i = 1;
for (double x : arr){
    mean = mean*((i-1)/i) + x/i;
    ++i; 
}
```

Calculating (i-1)/i first makes approaching zero, so x/i should be your only concern.

Answer (score -2):

Why so many complicated long answers. Here is the simplest way to find the running average till now without any need to know how many elements or size etc..

```
long int i = 0;
double average = 0;
while(there are still elements)
{
   average = average * (i / i+1) + X[i] / (i+1);
   i++;
}
return average;
```

Comment: -1 - This is a repeat of Martinus's answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930454/what-is-a-good-solution-for-calculating-an-average-where-the-sum-of-all-values-ex/1934266#1934266).

Comment: and it's completely wrong. `(i / i+1)` is always 2 unless i is zero