# Calculate average of a huge long array

Tags: java, arrays, performance, numbers

I'm trying to calculate the average of many (more than 200) `long` (primitive type) values stored in an array. Usually you add all the numbers and divide it by the number of the values. But this is not possible in this case since there is no primitive datatype in Java capable of holding such a large number, isn't it? Will `java.math.BigInteger` help here?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1930454/1223693

Comment: As you're asking about performance.... 1. don't optimize if you don't have to. 2. Using a hand-crafted mutable 128-bit integer would be at least twice as fast, but more work and error-prone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it will help you. An `BigInteger` can be as big as you want. Till there is not enough RAM.

With `BigInteger bigInt = BigInteger.valueOf(long);` you can convert the `Long` to an `BigInteger`.

And an `BigInteger` is immutable. So if you divide it like this `bigInt = bigInt.divide(BigInteger.valueOf(200));` You have to reassign it.

A more precise option would be the method `BigInteger.divideAndRemainder()`.

Comment: Of course, as you know, this will not necessarily give the big integer closest to the average of the values in the array.  Big integer division truncates so that if the true average were `10.99` this approach would return `10`.

Comment: Guava's `com.google.common.math.BigIntegerMath` has a `divide` method accepting an `RoundingMode`.

Answer (score 3):

Kai has a very good answer, but I'll just throw out there that if you know the exact number of values you are trying to average (and you do, since you said it was an array), then you can divide each value by N *before* adding them all up. Then you would never exceed the limit of `long`.

Example: the limit of `long` is roughly 9.22e18, so let's do an average near that limit:

```
    long[] arr = {Math.round(5e18), Math.round(9e18)};
    double avg = 0.0d;
    int size = arr.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        long l = arr[i];
        double tmp = l/(double)size;
        avg += tmp;
    }
```

(The `Math.round()` calls are needed since exponential notation numbers are doubles in Java.)

Comment: But that won't be pecise since the decimal points caused by that division fall away, right?

Comment: However you would lose a lot of accuracy (potentially all of it if the values are less than the length of the array). This might work if you stored them in doubles. `Double`s would be faster than `BigInteger`. `BigInteger` will be most accurate.

Comment: But then it would be possible that the data range of the `double` would not be enough.

Comment: No, you divide as you go. d = i[0]/3.0; d+= i[1]/3.0; d+=i[2]/3.0; No risk of overflow.

Comment: Oh yes, well, I assumed the average of the array of longs would be a `double`. You'd have to store each `arr[i]/N` as a double... if the desired result is a long, you could recast or round at the end.

Comment: Yes, but then again I'd preferr to use kai's solution.

Comment: That's fine too. Good luck to you!

Answer (score 2):

If you know that the sum of all the long values in your `array`/`list` will never exceed the `Long.MAX_VALUE` value, you can use the following to calculate the average:

```
// For long type array
long[] array = ...;
double average = LongStream.of(array).average().getAsDouble();

// For long type list
List<Long> list = ...;
double average = list.stream().mapToLong(n -> n).average().getAsDouble();
```

But if you're unsure about the sum of your list, and that it can even exceed the maximum limit that long primitive provides, then use the following method to calculate the average:

```
// For long type array
long[] array = ...;
BigInteger sum = LongStream.of(array).mapToObj(BigInteger::valueOf).reduce((x, y) -> x.add(y)).get();
BigDecimal average = new BigDecimal(sum).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(array.length));

// For long type list
List<Long> list = ...;
BigInteger sum = list.stream().map(BigInteger::valueOf).reduce((x, y) -> x.add(y)).get();
BigDecimal average = new BigDecimal(sum).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(list.size()));
```

This technique works from Java 8 and following imports are required:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.stream.LongStream;
```

Comment: Thank you! This approach is very simple but the downside is that is requires Java 1.8 in order to run.

Comment: @felixd: Agreed. But if one can update to Java 1.8, this approach provides a very neat solution. I just wanted you to be aware of this approach as well. :)

Answer (score 1):

- An average of a `long` is unlikely to be a `long`, so you need to decide for a type to keep your result. `BigDecimal` (not a `BigInteger` though) could be a good choice. You will probably need to define the accuracy of your result as well.
- Use a smarter algorithm to compute averages on massive collections. I do not have a definitive choice for you, but you could try something like this:

  1. initialise the value for your result as `BigDecimal` zero;
  2. compute a sum of next `M` elements and divide it by `N` where `N` is the total number of elements and `M<N`. The choice of `M` depends on the scale of your values and the accuracy your want to achive -- the larger the better, but think of your original problem;
  3. add this value to the result and go back to step 2 until all elements are used up

Comment: Your algorithm isn't smart, it's just complicated. For simplicity and speed, compute the sum (in a `BigInteger`) and then divide.

Comment: If "massive" is properly massive then a massive amount of memory will be needed to hold a sum in a `BigInteger`: the algorith is for "massive" arrays as the author specified. `BigInteger` cannot hold an accurate average of any numbers in a general case

Comment: @Oleg I can't remember typing "massive" anywhere ... And what do you mean with "massive amount of memory"?

Comment: @maaartinus That is what I'm most likely going to implement now.

Comment: @OlegS.: You're wrong again. For the sum of a billion longs you'd need 96 bits only.