# Calculate Mean and Standard Deviation

Tags: standard-deviation, mean, java

If I have a data feed of numbers for a variable, how can I calculate Mean and SD for this 
variable on the fly i.e update it every time a new input value becomes available.

I am looking for a solution in Java environment.

regards

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930454/what-is-a-good-solution-for-calculating-an-average-where-the-sum-of-all-values-e and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/895929/how-do-i-determine-the-standard-deviation-stddev-of-a-set-of-values/897463

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For mean:
You would keep two variables: 1. A runnting total 2. A running count of items seen so far. Mean is simply running total divided by running count.

For standard deviation:
[See John D. Cook's Accurately computing running variance](http://www.johndcook.com/standard_deviation.html). I have used it in the past in SQL using window function and found it very useful

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [SummaryStatistics class](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.2/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/descriptive/SummaryStatistics.html) in [Commons Math](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/) library to do this.

```
SummaryStatistics stats = new SummaryStatistics();
stats.addValue(1.0);
stats.addValue(2.0);
stats.addValue(3.5);
stats.addValue(8.0);

System.out.println("Mean: " + stats.getMean() + ", SD: " + stats.getStandardDeviation());
```