# Overflow When Calculating Average?

Tags: c++, math, overflow

Given 2 integer numbers we can calculate their average like this:

```
return (a+b)/2;
```

which isn't safe since (a+b) can cause overflow (Side Note: can someone tell me the correct term for this case maybe memory overflow?)

So we write:

```
return a+(b-a)/2;
```

can the same trick be implemented over `n` numbers and how?

Comment: Buffer Overflow, is this the correct term?

Comment: Integer overflow is often the term

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1934266/14215102 <- here's a trick for N numbers

Comment: @dratenik However, it is important to pay attention to the comment: `this algorithm will have severe underflow issues`

Comment: @dratenik With integers, you have the same overflow problem as the two valued examples in the question.

Answer (score 4):

Note that there are several different averages. I assume that you're asking about the arithmetic mean.

> overflow (Side Note: can someone tell me the correct term for this case maybe memory overflow?)

The correct term is arithmetic overflow, or just overflow. Not memory overflow.

> ```
> a+(b-a)/2;
> ```

`b-a` can also overflow. This isn't quite as easy to solve as it may seem.

Standard library has a function template to do this correctly without overflow: `std::midpoint`.

I checked an implementation of `std::midpoint`, and they do what you suggested for integers, except the operands are first converted to the corresponding unsigned type. Then the result is converted back. A mathematician may explain how that works, but I guess that it has something to do with the magic of modular arithmetic.

For floats, they do `a / 2 + b / 2` (if the inputs are normal).

> can the same trick be implemented over n numbers and how?

Simplest solution that works with all inputs without overflow and without imprecision is probably to use arbitrary precision arithmetic.

Comment: `std::midpoint` doesn't work for more than 2 arguments though right?

Comment: @mattlangford `midpoint` works for only 2 arguments

Comment: So `a / 2 + b / 2` can't overflow for integers?

Comment: @john It can't overflow, but you'll get a wrong result for many values if you're looking for arithmetic mean. Consider for example  `1 / 2 + 1 / 2 == 0`. Is 0 the average of array `[1, 1]`?

Comment: This here is a solution res = a/2.0 + b/2.0 @eerorika

Comment: @john doubles cannot precisely represent all integers. That would likely be imprecise if the inputs are 64 bit integers with large absolute values (Edit: actually it's worse: behaviour of converting unrepresentable integer to float is undefined). Also, there is no simple solution for precise average of many doubles (see the discussion about underflow in the comments under the question).

Comment: can you give an example @eerorika

Comment: @eerorika according to [conv.fpint] integer->floating may be imprecise, no UB; now FP->int is another matter

Comment: @dratenik That's not how I would interpret `[conv.fpint] A prvalue of an integer type or of an unscoped enumeration type can be converted to a prvalue of a floating-point type. ... If the value being converted is outside the range of values that can be represented, the behavior is undefined.`

Comment: @dratenik Although, I suppose that there might not be integer values that are outside the representable range (assuming IEEE-754).

Comment: @eerorika sure, if you have int128 and float32, you might hit that one, not with int64 and double

Answer (score 2):

One way of getting average number for multiple numbers is to find the Cumulative Moving Average, or CMA:

[image]

Your code `a + (b - a) / 2` can also be derived from this equation for `n + 1 == 2`.

---

Translating above equation to code, you would get something similar to:

```
std::vector<int> vec{10, 5, 8, 3, 2, 8}; // average is 6

double average = 0.0;

for(auto n = 0; n < vec.size(); ++n)
{
    average += (vec[n] - average) / (n + 1);
}

std::cout << average; // prints 6
```

Alternatively, you can also use the `std::accumulate`:

```
std::cout << std::accumulate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 0.0, 
                             [n = 0](auto cma, auto i) mutable {
                                 return cma + (i - cma) / ++n;
                             });
```

---

Do note any time you are using floating division can result into imprecise result, especially when you attempt to do that for numerous times. For more regarding impreciseness, you can look at: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: I think you should explain how CMA is initialised, and the type of CMA -- if it is integral the above won't always work. Indeed a snippet of code that could be compiled woud be best.